# In clojure , what is the idiomatic way to perform a serie of test functions on data , which each function having a sideeffect?

Tags: clojure

Let us suppose we are supposed to do an series of checks on email address and the data that is associated with the email:

1. Check if the email is nil ? if nil return {:msg "emial is nil"}
2. check if email has an account (i.e do a db lookup of the account for email). if account is nil , return {:msg "no account"}
3. check if the account is in expired. if accout is not in expired , return {:msg expired}

.. and so on

```
Currrently, I have coded this as nested if-let statements:
         (if-let [email (if (nil? email) nil email)]
               (if-let [acct (load-act email)]
                   (if-let [goodacct (if (expired? acct) nil acct)]    
                ....        
))
```

is there a nicer way or more idiomatic way to write this ?

Comment: Just to mention it: a term used to tackle this sort of problems is "railway orientated programming" and what is often used in FP circles is "Either".  Several libraries are around for that.  One honourable mention: [flow](https://github.com/fmnoise/flow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach: you model your user account as a plain map, and you define some basic validation functions. If it's just the first error that you are interested in, you can `map` the application of different functions across the same user account data, and pick the first error.

You can enhance this to collect all of the errors in a vector, or augmenting your map (eg. with `reduce`) so steps further down on the validation pipeline can re-use data obtained from side-effects from prior stages (eg. if a prior step went to the db, maybe `assoc` more keys into the map so that later validations can re-use the same data without extra queries. You'd need to change the validation functions to take a map and return a pair of `[updated-map error]`).

A quick and dirty example:

```clj
(defn valid-email [{:keys [email]}]
  (when-not email "email is nil"))

(defn valid-account [{:keys [account]}]
  (when-not account "no account"))

(defn expired-account [{:keys [account]}]
  (when (:expired account) "account expired"))

(def validations [valid-email valid-account expired-account])

(defn validator [user-data]
  (when-let [error (some identity (map #(% user-data) validations))]
    {:msg error}))

;; (validator {})
;; => {:msg "email is nil"}

;; (validator {:email "a@b.com"})
;; => {:msg "no account"}

;; (validator {:email "a@b.com" :account {:expired true}})
;; => {:msg "account expired"}

;; (validator {:email "a@b.com" :account {:expired false}})
;; => nil ;; nil means "no validation errors"
```

Comment: that is a nice abstraction and so easily extensible!

Comment: this code is very readable,easily testable, and it is easy to reason.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to factor this:

1) move the nil-check on e-mail higher up your chain. Then your function can do

```
(let [acct (load-act email)]
  (cond (nil? acct)     "no account"
        (expired? acct) "account expired"
        :else           acct))
```

2) not all of your tests really need to keep the result. The if-lets can be simplified to

```
(if (nil? email)
  "email is nil"
  (if-let [acct (load-act email)]
    (if (expired? acct)
      "account expired"
      acct)
    "no account"))
```

A side-note - clojure's notion of false-ness is `nil` and `false`. You're using a `nil?` check which really checks for `nil` only, and `if-let` which checks for `false` too. There's `if-some` which only does the `nil` check.

3) [`better-cond`](https://github.com/Engelberg/better-cond) allows binding inside its cond construct:

```
(b/cond
  (nil? email) "email is nil"
  :let [acct (load-act email)]
  (nil? acct) "no account"
  (expired? acct) "account expired"
  :else acct)
```

Answer (score 1):

The same like @xificurC's last version.
But why not use normal syntax? (no need for unnecessary dependencies ;) ).
Is not that more typing:

```
(cond (nil? email) {:msg "email is nil"}
      :else (let [acct (load-act email)]
              (cond (nil? acct) {:msg "no account"}
                    (expired? acct) {:msg "expired account"}
                    :else acct)))
```

Of course, one could discuss whether first `cond` should be an `if`.
But I like `cond`, because it lays down horizontally cause and effect on the left and right hand.
And the logic flows down like a waterfall but exits as soon as a condition is met.